# enzyme test not working after upgrade to React 16.4.1

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

We are upgrading from React 16.2 to 16.4.1.

This test is now failing.  What do we need to do to simulate this?

```
        describe('EditableCardTitle rendering', () => {
describe('render title', () => {
    const widgetId = '123456789';
    const cardTitle = 'cardTitle';
    const renderedElement = mount(
        <EditableCardTitle editable={true} widgetId={widgetId} cardTitle={cardTitle} onSave={jest.fn} saveMetadata={jest.fn} />
    );

    it('should render an updated title when the user changes the text', () => {
        const inputElements = renderedElement.find('.input').find('input');
        inputElements.simulate('blur', {
            target: {
                value: 'newCardTitle'
            }
        });

        expect(inputElements.instance().defaultValue).toBe('newCardTitle');
    });
});
```

});

Comment: In what way is the test failing?

Comment: It does not change the value to newCardTitle

Comment: Can you provide more code examples please. Just from the test example it's very difficult to tell what else is happening